# Why does a more efficient algorithm run slower?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, time-complexity, runtime

I'm new here, and if my question is not relevant, please delete it. I had a doubt while solving the following problem on [LeetCode](https://leetcode.com/):

> 70 - Climbing Stairs:
>   You are climbing a stair case. It takes N steps to reach to the top.
>   Each time you can either climb 1 or 2 steps. In how many distinct ways can you climb to the top?
>
> **Note:** Given n will be a positive integer.

Example 1:

- Input: 2
- Output: 2

Explanation: There are two ways to climb to the top.

1. One step **then** another step
2. Two steps **at a time**.

I know two solutions of this problem:

- One that calculates **all possible step combinations** at **every step**:

  ```
  public class Solution {
      public int climbStairs(int n) {
          climb_Stairs(0, n);
      }
      public int climb_Stairs(int i, int n) {
          if (i > n) {
              return 0;
          }
          if (i == n) {
              return 1;
          }
          return climb_Stairs(i + 1, n) + climb_Stairs(i + 2, n);
      }
  }
  ```
- And another one that uses **dynamic programming**:

  ```
  public class Solution {
      public int climbStairs(int n) {
          if (n == 1) {
              return 1;
          }
          int[] dp = new int[n + 1];
          dp[1] = 1;
          dp[2] = 2;
          for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
              dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2];
          }
          return dp[n];
      }
  }
  ```

It is obvious that the second is much more efficient than the first. However, when I submit them, LeetCode shows nearly the same runtime, around 4ms. Shouldn't the second have a much shorter runtime than the first?

Comment: Yes, it does, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested your implementation with different step counts. The code is below, at the end of the answer.

- For **3** steps, `n = 3`, I got this output:

  ```
  Time spent for 3 step(s):
       - climbStairsByComputingAllNextSteps(): 6243 nanoseconds
       - climbStairsDynamically(): 25236 nanoseconds
  ```

Oh, the more efficient is the slower one? Well, let's do another test :

- For **20** steps, `n = 20`, I got this output:

  ```
  Time spent for 20 step(s):
       - climbStairsByComputingAllNextSteps(): 1048360 nanoseconds
       - climbStairsDynamically(): 5657 nanoseconds
  ```

So the efficiency of your implementation *depends* on `n`.

Of course, the **[time complexity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)** of your **algorithm** has a high impact on the **efficiency** (sorry if it's not the relevant term) of your **code**. But for two given algorithms, one could be the **more** efficient for **`n < nmax value`**, then become the **less** one for **`n >= nmax`**.

Look at this graph taken from Wikipedia (by [Cmglee](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Cmglee) - license [CC BY-SA 4.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/deed.en), taken from the article linked above):

[image: Comparison computational complexity by Cmglee - CC BY-SA 4.0]

The **`nlog`<sub>`2`</sub>`n`** curve seems to cost **more** than the **`n`** one, *except in the neighborhood of 0* **`(0 <= n < ~1)`**. This neighborhood could vary. Here, the point where their efficiency switch seems to be **`n=6`**.

Below the working sample I used (tried with [Online Java Compiler](https://www.jdoodle.com/online-java-compiler)).

```
public class Solution {
    public static void climbStairsByComputingAllNextSteps(int n) {
        processNextClimbingByComputingAllNextSteps(0, n);
    }
    private static int processNextClimbingByComputingAllNextSteps(int i, int n) {
        if (i > n) {
            return 0;
        }
        if (i == n) {
            return 1;
        }
        return
        processNextClimbingByComputingAllNextSteps(i + 1, n) +
        processNextClimbingByComputingAllNextSteps(i + 2, n);
    }

    public static int climbStairsDynamically(int n) {
        if (n == 1) {
            return 1;
        }
        int[] dp = new int[n + 1];
        dp[1] = 1;
        dp[2] = 2;
        for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++) {
            dp[i] = dp[i - 1] + dp[i - 2];
        }
        return dp[n];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime, diffTime;
    int steps;

    try {
        steps= Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        steps=10;
    }

    System.out.println("Time spent for " + steps + " step(s):");
    System.out.print("\t - climbStairsByComputingAllNextSteps(): ");
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    climbStairsByComputingAllNextSteps(steps);
    diffTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println(diffTime + " nanoseconds");
    System.out.print("\t - climbStairsDynamically(): ");
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    climbStairsDynamically(steps);
    diffTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println(diffTime + " nanoseconds");

    }

}
```